# Postrgersql+Django: NULL value causes IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: django, postgresql, null

I have the following table:

```
   Column      |            Type             |                           Modifiers                           
----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
user_id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('employee_user_id_seq'::regclass) 
name            | character varying(50)       | not null                                                      
phonenumber     | character varying(20)       | not null                                                      
phonenumber2    | character varying(20)       |                                                               
email           | character varying(75)       |      
Indexes:
"employee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id)
"employee_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
"employee_phonenumber2_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (phonenumber2)
"employee_phonenumber_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (phonenumber, email)
"employee_phonenumber_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (phonenumber)
```

in models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    phonenumber2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
```

using Django I've inserted an Employee without phonenumber2 into the table. First time it goes smooth cause it's the first NULL then at the second try I get the error:

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "employee_phonenumber2_key"
DETAIL:  Key (phonenumber2)=() already exists.
```

from my understanding NULL should not be considered as a value for the constraints, what I'm trying to achieve is that same phone number or combination of phone number and email can not be duplicated for different employees.

How can I fix this?

Comment: "models.py". Taking a wild guess, you're using Django? (This is the sort of thing it's nice to mention, or at least tag).

Answer (score 2):

You're not really inserting `NULL` at all, you're inserting the empty string `''`. If you were inserting `NULL`, it would not be possible to get the error you show.  If you want a unique constraint to ignore `NULL`, you must actually use `NULL`.

If you examine the PostgreSQL server error logs you will see the query that was run; you might need to turn `log_statement = all` on to get all the details, though. It will show that you were `INSERT`ing `''` for `phonenumber2`, not `NULL`.

To conclusively demonstrate this:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT phonenumber2_nonempty 
CHECK (phonenumber2 IS NULL OR length(phonenumber2) > 0);
```

it'll reject any rows that have zero length strings. Including the one you've already added that you thought was null, so adding the check constraint will fail.

You appear to be using Django, going by your mention of "models.py". Django has the IMO poor notion that the Python value `None` should be stored in character fields as `''`, not `NULL`; it treats both `''` and `None` as "empty values". [You can tell it to store None as `NULL` with `Field.null`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/). I'm not sure if it'll then also force `''` to be stored as `NULL`; I hope not, but haven't tested.

Comment: @liva Suggest a new question for that if you can't figure it out after looking into it for a bit. I don't use Django.